# How to fix this javascript switch statement problem, switch statement arent working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to getelemtbyid from a selection list and storing that selected value in a variable. and trying to execute switch case against that value(getelemtbyid). But switch is not working on that variable.
value is getting successfully but switch is not working even that IF else is also not working with that variable.

I also tried typecasting but its not working.

```
<select id="from">
  <option value="1">car 1</option>
  <option value="2">car 2</option>
  <option value="3">car 3</option>
</select>
```

---

```
<script>
var b = document.getElementById("from").value;
var c = Number(b); //type casting ... didnt helped in working with switch

//b var is not working with switch  
switch (b) {
  case '1':
    {
      alert("i am case 1");
      case '2':
        {
          alert('i am case 2');
        }
        break;
    }
  default:
    {
      alert("i am default");
      break;
    }
}

</script>
```

switch should execute the respective case against switch variable

Comment: if c is a number, perhase `case 1:` etc

Comment: those `{}` look badly placed

Comment: What you’ve written in the question is just a syntax error. Please make sure it reflects your actual code instead.

Comment: Welcome to web-development. You need to know the tools you have at your disposition in order to debug your code on your own. Your will-be best friend is called the [web-console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console). Look at it, and forget about `alert()`, forever.

Comment: The `alert()` will block the UI of the browser and the execution of the js code in the page. Use `console.log()` instead to allow the page to keep running even while logging information in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Your `switch` structure is malformed due to the placement of the braces. Remove these & your `switch` should work:

```
<script>
    var b = document.getElementById("from").value;
    var c = Number(b); //type casting ... didnt helped in working with switch

    switch (b) {
      case '1':
          alert("i am case 1");
      case '2':
          alert('i am case 2');
          break;
      default:
          alert("i am default");
          break;
    }
</script>
```

Alternatively, move your `case '2'` section out of `case '1'`:

```
<script>
    var b = document.getElementById("from").value;
    var c = Number(b); //type casting ... didnt helped in working with switch

    switch (b) {
      case '1':
        {
          alert("i am case 1");
        }
      case '2':
        {
          alert('i am case 2');
          break;
        }
      default:
        {
          alert("i am default");
          break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`c` is a number - it's the parsed number of the string `b`. So check the number `c` like so:

```
case 1:
    //Code
case 2:
    //Code
default:
    //Code
```

Comment: yes it is supposed to be a number after type casting but still its not working, i have also tried type casting it in string

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `switch` statement here.. That way you reduce code complexity..

- Also no need to use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) as there is not any numerical operations here

Code:

```js
document
  .getElementById('from')
  .addEventListener('change', function() {
    alert(`i am case ${this.value}`)
  });
```

```html
<select id="from">
  <option value="default"> - </option>
  <option value="1">car 1</option>
  <option value="2">car 2</option>
  <option value="3">car 3</option>
</select>
```

Note that in the example i have added [Event​Target​.add​Event​Listener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to show alert on change.. Just for the demo code

Comment: Are you really assuming they only want to have an alert box stating what the user did choose?

Comment: No you don't get me... The code in this question is **obviously** an [MCVE], not what they actually want to achieve. The logic inside this switch statement will probably be more complex than just `alert(input.value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You made a syntax error for switch ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

```js
document.getElementById("from").addEventListener('change', function(e) {
 var b = document.getElementById("from").value;
 var c = Number(b); //type casting ... didnt helped in working with switch

 
switch (b) {
  case '1':
            alert("i am case 1");
            break;
      case '2':
            alert('i am case 2');
            break;

  default:
      alert("i am default");
      break;
  
}
}, false);
```

```html
<select id="from">
  <option value="1">car 1</option>
  <option value="2">car 2</option>
  <option value="3">car 3</option>
</select>
```